# Click operation in Geb not working

Tags: groovy, selenium, webdriver, geb

I'am new to geb, I have a page with a form like this

```
        <form id="loginfrm1" action="http://google.co.uk">
            <input id="loginsubmit1" type="submit" value="sumit me" />
        </form>
```

I want to click on the submit button, I'm using

```
browser = new Browser()
browser.setDriver(new FirefoxDriver())
browser.go("http://localhost:8080")
browser.$("#loginsubmit1").click()
```

But it doesn't seem to work. Where am I going wrong?

**Update**: I temporarily got it working by changing the operation to a normal webdriver  operation, like this

```
    browser.driver.findElement(By.id('loginsubmit1')).submit()
```

I don't know what is wrong with this command

```
browser.$("#loginsubmit1").click()
```

Answer (score 0):

$() isn't available on the browser object, just the page.  This code should work:

```
browser = new Browser()
browser.setDriver(new FirefoxDriver())
browser.go("http://localhost:8080")
browser.$("#loginsubmit1").page.click()
```

You should also consider using the Browser.drive method.  For what you want, it would look like this:

```
Browser.drive(baseUrl: "http://localhost:8080"){
    go()
    $("#loginsubmit1").click()
}
```

It works because drive() creates a new browser object and delegates to both it and browser.page, so whatever methods and properties they have can be called directly.  You don't need to specify FirefoxDriver because that is its default, but if you did want to specify it, you would do it like so:

```
Browser.drive(baseUrl: "http://localhost:8080", 
    driver: new FirefoxDriver()){ ...
```